# Pass testcase if element is present on page - Selenium w/ python

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to pass the test case if the welcome button is present on the page post-login. Unable to figure out the right way to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium .webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Downloads/Drivers/chromedriver 2')
        self.driver.get('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php')


    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def testValidLogin(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtUsername').send_keys('Admin')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtPassword').send_keys('admin123')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10)
        welcomebtn = self.driver.find_element_by_id('welcome')
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(welcomebtn))
        self.assertEquals(True, welcomebtn.is_displayed())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

getting error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="welcome"]"}
```

Comment: could you provide more details on how exactly it isn't working (such as an error message, or what behavior is unexpected)

Comment: Added the error message, thanks